# Silent Authentication in Actionscript without generating the dialog box

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I need to send the device token required for push notification in iOS to urban-airship server from the actionscript code. How can i do that? I am using their API's in my app. I am just using urban-airship to test push notifications on my app. 
Since their url requires user authentication, I want to write code so that authentication happens silently without generating the pop dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out myself how to solve this problem:

```
// AIR developer can send the tokenId received in event.data to his server via URL request 
var urlRequest:URLRequest;
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var tokenId:String; //tokenId received after registering for push notifications
var urlString:String = "https://go.urbanairship.com/api/device_tokens/" + tokenId;
urlRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
urlRequest.authenticate = true;
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.PUT;
URLRequestDefaults.setLoginCredentialsForHost("go.urbanairship.com",<userId>,<password>) ;
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
urlLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, onStatus);
```